# JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<> returns null in xamarin studio on mac using Json.Net

Tags: c#, xaml, json.net, xamarin-studio, json-deserialization

Following is my .xaml.cs file :

```
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace JSONConversion
{
    public partial class JSONConversionPage : ContentPage
    {
        public JSONConversionPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            var myString = @"{""id"":""1"",""row"":""10""}";
            TestData testData = new TestData();
            testData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TestData>(myString);

            Debug.WriteLine("Row: " + testData.row);
        }

    }

    [JsonObject]
    public class TestData
    {
        [JsonProperty("id")]
        public string id { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("row")]
        public string row { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Here testData object always contains null. The JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(myString) seems to be returning null. I checked a lot of posts here and checked each solution, but no luck. What can be the possible issue?

Comment: Try with `var myString =  "{'id':'1','row':'10'}";`

Comment: I find that hard to believe.  The data matches the expected structure.  What do you mean by it always contains null?  You get a NullReferenceException? The debug output shows null?  You get no output?  Have you tried just doing a simple console application to see if it deserializes?

Comment: @NKosi  I have tried that too.

Comment: @Jeff Mercado When I tried to debug, testData.row has null value. When I write that line to application output, nothing is displayed(coz no value is set). It probably isn't deserialising the data. But I don't understand why.

Comment: Tested it on dotnetfiddle and it works fine. - https://dotnetfiddle.net/TfDbTX

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve the result using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

```
public JSONConversionPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        var myString = @"{""id"":""1"",""row"":""10""}";
        var testData = JObject.Parse(myString);
        Debug.WriteLine("Row: " + testData["row"]);
    }
```

testData["row"] shows the value 10